# Restart Jupyter Lab server running in the background

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to restart a Jupyter Lab server (not just the kernels) running in the background of an AWS SageMaker notebook instance. I have already tried the following:

- Killing the server by it's process ID

  - `pgrep` doesn't show me the process
  - `pkill` can't find the process
  - `ps aux` shows the process ID as constantly changing
- Stopping the server through `jupyter notebook stop`

  - I get an SSL error and nothing happens

The only thing I've been able to do is reboot the entire instance, which isn't a great option as it can take awhile to become available again.

Edit 1:

The main reason I am trying to do this is that after installing the `tqdm` package and trying to use `tqdm.notebook` in Jupyter Lab, in order for it to display correctly I need to enable/install notebook and lab extensions. In order for these to take effect the server then needs to be restarted.

Comment: What is the motivation behind restarting the underlying Jupyter server?

Comment: When you shutdown a SageMaker notebook instance it acts like a factory reset. So every time I start it again I have to reinstall extensions to Jupyter Lab (in this case it's for tqdm), and then I need to restart the server for them to work.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to reset the memory space for cells/work done within your JupyterLab notebooks without completely wiping the underlying environment changes since instance start (ie: extensions/plugins installed)?

Comment: I just need to restart the Jupyter server or kill the server process (the notebook instance automatically restarts the server if it crashes). I don't care if the kernels are killed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Left hand navbar, `Commands`
2. Navigate to the `Help` section on the popout menu
3. Reset Application State

Answer (score 3):

Both classic Jupyter and Jupyter lab live within the same process.

`sudo initctl restart jupyter-server --no-wait` is what AWS suggest in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=917594&#917594

Comment: I get the error `sudo: initctl: command not found`

Comment: I have the same error posted here: https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-explaining-credit-decisions/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it runs on port 8888:

```
jupyter lab stop 8888 && jupyter lab
```

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is on Amazon Linux 1, use

`sudo initctl restart jupyter-server --no-wait`

If your instance is on Amazon Linux 2, use

`sudo systemctl restart jupyter-server`, which is equivalent to `sudo service jupyter-server restart`.